# "Волчий билет" — откуда пошло выражение?

Tags: этимология, фразеология, значение-слов

**Волчьим билетом** называют, как я понимаю, отсутствие документа, например, об образовании. (Выпустить из школы с волчьим билетом.)
А откуда такое выражение пошло?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лично мне во всех объяснениях не нравится только одно.
Все обращают внимание именно на прилагательное "волчий", а оно-то как может быть объяснено десятком вполне правдоподобных вариантов.

А вот "билет"... Это-то самое интересное, т.н. "Заменительный билет" - название целого ряда документов, выдаваемых в Российской империи взамен утерянных или изъятых уполномоченными на то органами, обычно - полицией, реже жандармерией, аппаратом градоначальника (тогдашнего мэра) и проч. Единых внутренних паспортов тогда не существовало, обычной заменой был т.н. вид на жительство. Вот его-то добровольно или принудительно за какую-либо деятельность (обычно - неблагонадежность), часто меняли на "заменительные билеты".
Наиболее известный тип заменительного билета - т.н. [жёлтый билет](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%96%D1%91%D0%BB%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82).

Волчьими же такие билеты прозвали видимо потому, что его обладатель подобно волку был разрешенным объектом охоты без всяких ограничений. До санитаров леса тогда еще не додумались.

"Волчий билет", судя по всему, изначально выглядел примерно так же, но название быстро распространилось на всякого рода документ с ограничением  прав. И даже на сам факт запрета заниматься какой-либо деятельностью. Особо это касалось учащихся гимназий и студентов. Никакого билета на самом деле не выдавалось, хотя по некоторым сведениям могла делаться отметка в аттестате, но это явно не было обязательным. Запрет на поступления в образовательные учреждения действовал, однако, весьма эффективно, тогдашняя система слежки и доносительства работала без сбоев.

Comment: Ну да,как и "белый билет"для военнообязанных:
http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82. Только автору вопроса, по-моему, интересно и название "волчий".Белый, жёлтый - цвет реального документа, а вот иметь"волчий билет" - быть отвергнутым обществом.

Comment: Людмила, белый билет - это много более позднее. А про "волчий" я сказал, версий может быть много, но большинство никак не связаны с билетом.

Answer (score 3):

**Волчий билет** (волчий паспорт) – в XIX веке название документа, закрывающего доступ на государственную службу, учебное заведение и т. п. Сегодня фразеологизм употребляется в значении резко отрицательной характеристики о работе кого-либо.

**Происхождение** этого оборота обычно объясняют тем, что человеку, получившему такой документ, не разрешалось жить на одном месте более 2-3 дней и ему приходилось скитаться, подобно волку. Кроме этого, во многих сочетаниях волчий означает "ненормальный, нечеловеческий, звериный" (ср.: волчий аппетит, волчьи законы, волчья ягода и др.), что усиливает противопоставление между обладателем волчьего билета и прочими "нормальными" людьми.
(Из Грамоты.ру)

Answer (score 3):

http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C2%EE%EB%F7%E8%E9_%E1%E8%EB%E5%F2

По одной из версий, термин «волчий билет» произошёл от прозвища обитателей ночлежного дома «Сухой овраг», который находился между Хитровской площадью и Свиньинским переулком в Москве: этих ночлежников называли «волки Сухого оврага». Среди них было множество мелких уголовников, нищих и административно высланных, то есть лиц, обладавших «волчьими паспортами» — документами, по которым нельзя было жить в Москве.

По Ушакову: Волчий паспорт или билет (дореволюц. разг.) — свидетельство, паспорт с отметкой о неблагонадежности, закрывавший доступ на государственную службу, в учебные заведения и т. п.

По Далю: Волчий билет (народн.) — полугодовая отсрочка, выдаваемая приговоренным к ссылке преступникам, от которых общество отрекается.

В советские времена - запись в трудовой об увольнении по статье.В наше время "волчий билет" - "чёрный список". То есть если работодатель хочет навести справки о кандидате, который пришёл к нему устраиваться, то он может узнать, есть ли он в списке тех, кто  профессионально неблагонадёжен.(список неофициален, это мнение работодателей, своеобразная характеристика)